# Match template picture on camera screen with actual image which is scanned through camera android

Tags: opencv, android, template-matching

I am trying to develop an android app, that matches template picture on camera screen with actual image which is scanned through camera [check image to get clarified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2RYn.png)

the four green circles on the template image appearing on camera screen should match with the four circles appearing in the background image which I will be scanning through the camera, exactly as shown in fig... once the four circles of template image matches with four circles of background image, a toast will get appeared

How to achieve this? i ve gone through openCV template matching, but couldnt achieve this..

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many algorithms in opencv used to match images. I recommend finding features and descriptors of the two images using sift or surf and use brute force matcher or falnn matcher. and check the good matches if there are enough good matches then the object is found and toast the message.

Answer (score 0):

I would just try to find the four circles using HoughCircles and check their positions.

Parameter setting for HoughCircles will be a bit tricky, so try with different values until you see the stable result. The min/max Radius parameters should be as narrow as possible to save computing time and avoid invalid results.

Comment: Thanks, will try this